# Selected Item Background?

Tags: wpf, listbox, togglebutton

I have a `ListBox` with a buttons `DataTemplate`.  The `ListBox` view items are in a list of `ToggleButton`s.

My problem is the with selected item background as shown in picture:

[image]

As shown, the problem is in button one.  This screenshot was taken when the wpf page is first loaded (before the toggle button is checked).  If I then check the togglebutton (button one) the white in the border will disappear

I don't want this white color shown (like two button).
I have:

```
   <ListBox x:Name="lbname" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" Margin="432,110,0,158" Width="214" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <!-- SelectedItem with focus -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                   Color="Transparent" />
                    <!-- SelectedItem without focus -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                   Color="Transparent" />
                    <!-- SelectedItem text foreground -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                   Color="Black" />
                </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnname" tyle="{StaticResource ToggleStyle}" FontFamily="tahoma" FontSize="14" Height="55" Width="208" FontWeight="Normal" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Checked="btnname_Checked" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Height="55" Width="205">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/two.png" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/myApplication;component/images/buttons/one.png" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the style you are using?

Comment: You have explained your problem well, but it would help greatly if you posted the entire XAML that you use to display these buttons in the listbox.

Comment: i have update my question with XAML code for listbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this `Style` to override the default styling of the `ListBoxItem`:

```
<Style x:Key="HiddenDefaultSelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

You can of course replace these colours with whatever you prefer. You can use it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HiddenDefaultSelectionStyle}" />
```

Or you can remove the `x:Key="HiddenDefaultSelectionStyle"` declaration and then it will affect every `ListBoxItem` in scope.

Comment: still the same issue :(

Comment: I just loaded your XAML into a new WPF project and it all works just fine... there are no white backgrounds behind the buttons that I can see.

Comment: the white background appears only for first load, after checked the button it disappears, any way,  I've added the answer and thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi Sheridan,
My question is marked as duplicate. But I can not solve with your answer. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

oky, finaly i have solved my issue via using the below style

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="NoSelectionItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I suggest that you read some WPF books or tutorials online. There are *way* simpler methods of achieving what you want. For other SO users... please keep searching as this solution is far from optimal.

Comment: I agree with you that it probably is not optimal solution, but it works,Theoretically the solution that you typed solution is logical, but it does not work.

Comment: Oh please... my comment has absolutely nothing to do with my answer... does it look like I need reputation points? I merely added the comment because there is no need to declare a `ControlTemplate` or use a `ContentControl` to achieve what you want. I simply didn't want other users to think that this is the best way to do this. Apologies if I hurt your feelings.

Comment: Sheridan,there is no need to apologize,the goal is reach the optimal solution. there is no problem at all, and I'm still looking forward for a perfect solution, if you get it I hope you share it with me, and i would thank you so much to help me.